# VIM functionality in terminal command writing

Tags: linux, vim, terminal

Is it posible to have vim functionality while I'm writing in terminal. The catch is that I'm doing alot of server maintainings and It's pain to have only left right navigation when something in command is wrong and the cursor is on the end, for example let we say we have this line of code already executed in terminal with an error on printfUPS

```
$ find ./ -name \* -printfUPS '%CD\t%p\n' | grep "03/10/08" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -t -i mv {} temp/
```

I will go aero up to browse 1 history up, press <- home (cursor on begining), press for 2 sec right aero and my cursor is finaly on printfUPS... What a pain in the but.

If the vim would be posible I will make changes on code in 0.5 sec and spend more time with the bosses dog :D.

So pls help me out I really love bosses dog. :D

Comment: `fc` (for fix command) will open the last command line in your $EDITOR.  If your bash is in emacs mode, you can use `Ctrl-x Ctrl-e` to open the current command line in an editor, or `ESC v` if you're in vi mode.

Comment: Cool this one is really good, thx for your input :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using bash try typing in this command:

set -o vi

You will always start in insert mode, but if you press ESC you will go into command mode and can use all your usual vim keys to move around.

(If this answered your question please mark it as an answer. I'm trying to get enough reputation points to vote on something.)

Comment: Nice, this is what i was hoping to achive :D @jaszakmeister 's comment is also close one. Reputation points for you good sir. :D

Comment: This is just perfection. TYVM